# Service to store images online for fast loading on mobile

Tags: flutter, image, performance, mobile, cdn

I am finalizing the development of a mobile application in Flutter but I am facing a problem.
I have a page on which I load a large number of images that are stored on my OVH server (in France).

On this page, the images are displayed at about **150x150px** (many other elements are loaded below).

[image]

The problem is that I am storing these images in **higher size** (At least 1000x1000px), because I am displaying them in another location in large format.
So, when the user goes to the page, there are many large images to load (*displayed in small format*) and it is really long.

**I wanted to know if you have any solutions for me. I know by name CDNs, which can store images and retrieve them via URLs like https://example/my_pic?size=150x150.**

If there is no such thing, I was thinking of simply creating smaller copies of my images on my server to load them more quickly on this page.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of CDNs have services that you're looking for.  CloudFlare has image resizing (docs [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/image-resizing/)). Another option could be Cloudinary (docs [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/resizing_and_cropping)).  If you wanted to optimize or store it yourself, you could look at graphicsMagik (docs [here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html))